# CSS: Background Color on Element With Automatic Width

Tags: css

**The problem domain.**
I would like to style a HTML list using CSS. The list will serve as a navigation bar and always be on screen. To avoid wasting screen space, the menu should by default be in a collapsed state and only expand on mouse-over.

**Expected behaviour.** 
If not hovered-over, the navigation should only display the list’s numbering. If the user hovers over one list item, it should expand to show that item’s text. The navigation bar’s background color should extend to the end of that text, but only around the item which is hovered over. That is, the item should “pop out” of the navigation.

**Actual behaviour.** I cannot find a way to make the background color work in this scenario. If the list item’s width is set to auto, then the text appears as it should, but the background color doesn’t extend with the list item. If I set a fixed width for the list item (l. 33 in the fiddle), e.g. 300px, then the background color *does* extend with the text, but I wish to avoid static sizes. Why do static widths behave differently from automatic ones?

**I’ve tried** fixed positioning of hovered-over list items. That would create the effect I have in mind, but it also has two undesirable side-effects: It removes the automatic numbering from the selected item, and it removes the item from the text flow, which makes the successive items move up in the list. Both of them would have to be compensated for manually, which I’d like to avoid.

**JSFiddle and Code**
This fiddle illustrates the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/3n8g03y9/

```css
body {
  /* For better visibility of white text */
  background-color: #002;
}


/* Container div */

#navigation {
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 20pt;
  display: block;
  background-color: #333;
  /* dark grey */
}


/* Main topic list */

#navigation>ol {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 40px;
}


/* Main topic entry */

#navigation>ol>li {
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #333;
  #333;
  /* dark grey */
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Only show the number until hover */
  width: 30px;
  /* 40px minus the OL’s padding */
}


/* Hover over main topic entry */

#navigation>ol>li:hover {
  width: auto;
  overflow: visible;
  ;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
  <ol>
    <li> Topic 1</li>
    <li> Topic 2</li>
    <li> Topic 3</li>
    <li> Topic 4</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/3n8g03y9/1/ ?

Comment: Or this https://jsfiddle.net/3n8g03y9/3/ ?

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but I’ll go for MikkelTN’s solution. It’s simpler.

Comment: Make sure you select it as the answer to give him credit

Comment: @sn3ll I like to wait a little before doing that. There may be even better answers around the corner and I don’t want to discourage their posters, especially since this answer can further be improved. I feel like the accepted answer tag makes this question look solved; no further input required. But I’ll definitely mark it soon; thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is to use set your li elements to float, like this:

```
/* Main topic entry */
    #navigation > ol > li{
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: left; /* Add this to show background when hovering */
    background-color: #333; /* dark grey */
    color: white;
    overflow: hidden; /* Only show the number until hover */
    width: 30px; /* 40px minus the OL’s padding */
```

Check this pen for demo: http://codepen.io/MikkelTN/pen/XMoxEa

Comment: It does solve the problem. Do you happen to know why the items have to float for their background to show and why there is a difference between `width: auto` and `width: 200px` when it comes to the rendering of background color?

Comment: Width: auto will not extend the width of a child element  beyond the parent, unless said child is floated, whereas a set width will. If a child element is floated, it is 'removed' from the standard flow and is no longer defined by its parent's dimensions. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes it does. I forgot that the list items are—of course—children of the list whose fixed width then caused the behaviour.
Thanks!